# Google Drive API in PHP

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I had a problem on making the Google Drive API work. I want to allow public user to search on my file list and upload files to my Google Drive.

I created an API key on my developer console and added it to the following script and try to read a list of my files, but didn't work. It returned "500 Internal Server Error". Do I miss anything?

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setDeveloperKey("MY_API_KEY");
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"); 

$dr_service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

$dr_results = $dr_service->files->listFiles(array('maxResults' => 10))
```

I tried to use ClientID (see the following code) and it works but I don't want to prompt the user to login to their google account and I want them to do everything on my account. Or how can I call the oauth with my account without prompting the user?

```
    session_start();

    require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php';

    $client = new Google_Client();

    // Get your credentials from the console
    $client->setClientId('MY_CLIENT_ID');
    $client->setClientSecret('MY_CLIENT_SECRET');
    $client->setRedirectUri('MY_URL');
    $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));


    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {

        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);  
        $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        header('Location: http://MY_URL');

    }

    if (!$client->getAccessToken() && !isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
    }        

   if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
       print "<a class='logout' href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?logout=1'>LogOut</a><br>";
       $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);

       $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
       var_dump($service->files->ListFiles());

    }
```

Comment: *"didn't work"* is a terrible problem description. What did you expect to happen? What actually happened? Have you enabled error reporting and were there any errors?

Answer (score 2):

download the files from here [google drive client](https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-php/tree/master/google-api-php-client/src) in a folder `google_drive`.Then try this code

include the three files .

```
require 'google_drive/Google_Client.php';
require 'google_drive/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';
require 'google_drive/socialmedia_oauth_connect.php';
```

create new object of the classess.

```
$client_gd = new Google_Client();
$service = new Google_DriveService($client_gd);
$file=new Google_DriveFile();
```

set access token

```
if(isset($_GET['code']))
{
    $authCode = $_REQUEST['code'];
    $accessToken = $client_gd->authenticate($authCode);
    $_SESSION['access_token_gd']=$accessToken;
    $client_gd->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    $about = $service->about->get();
    $user=$about['permissionId'];
    $_SESSION['gd_user']=$user;
    $_SESSION['user_info_gd']=$about;
    header('location:'.HOME.'?index_gd=1');

}
```

authenticate with google drive

```
 $authUrl = $client_gd->createAuthUrl();
            //$clientid = $gdsettings->gdclient_id;
           // $clientsec = $gdsettings->gdclient_secret;
            $redirecturi = HOME.'index.php';
     $oauth = new socialmedia_oauth_connect();

            $oauth->provider="Google";
            global $apiConfig;
            $oauth->client_id = $apiConfig['oauth2_client_id'];
            $oauth->client_secret = $apiConfig['oauth2_client_secret'];
            $oauth->scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.apps.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://docs.google.com/feeds/ https://docs.googleusercontent.com/ https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/";
            $oauth->redirect_uri = $apiConfig['oauth2_redirect_uri'];
            $oauth->approval_prompt = "force";

            $oauth->Initialize();
            $oauth->Authorize();
```

get the files

```
    $accessToken=$_SESSION['access_token_gd'];
            $client_gd->setAccessToken($accessToken);
            //print_r($client_gd->getAccessToken());
            //List of files
            $arr = array();
            $files = $service->files->listFiles();
            $about = $service->about->get();

            $user=$about['permissionId'];
            //$_SESSION['gd_user']=$user;
            //$_SESSION['user_info_gd']=$about;
            $drivefiles = $files["items"];
 foreach($drivefiles as $divefl )
  {
echo $divefl['title'];

}
```

here is the full description you can read [google drive client integration](https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-php)